# Love, Victor: Love, Simon Jacket Reference

Tags: reference, cameo, love-simon, love-victor

In Season 1, Episode 8 of *Love, Victor*, Simon (from *Love, Simon*) makes a cameo. He gives Victor his jacket and sais this:

> "Bram said he would burn it if I wore it one more time"

I know that this is a reference to Love, Simon but what exactly is this reference?

The scene (starts at 2:15):

Comment: [It is actually the very denim jacket that Nick Robinson is seen wearing in Love, Simon.](https://jxxspzd.com/love-victor-hidden-details-main-character/)

Comment: @BCdotWEB I know this, but I'm pretty sure that the comment of Brett disliking the jacket is another reference, which I cannot find out about...

Comment: @taylor.2317 I think it was more of a joke that Simon wear only one jacket so much which his bf got annoyed with